# Element not identified when not being focus on chrome window in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a whatsapp bot, when the user opens other programs on the whatsapp window and this whatsapp window loses focus, it doesn't get some elements right. I tried to use `headless` but it now doesn't see any elements. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the screen size?
The default screen size for headless mode is significantly smaller than the default screen size in regular mode.
Try setting it as following:

```py
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Or via the `options` parameters:

```py
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```